# How to insert additional element to third-party component?

Tags: reactjs

I use the third-party component named "slider" ([rc-slider](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rc-slider)). I need to add an additional element inside the slider slider (`div class = "rc-slider-handle"`).

```
<div class="rc-slider">
   <div class="rc-slider-rail" style="..."></div>
   <div class="rc-slider-track" style="..."></div>
   <div class="rc-slider-step"></div>
   <div role="slider" tabindex="0" ... class="rc-slider-handle" style="..."> 
       // new element should be added here
   </div>
   <div class="rc-slider-mark"></div>
</div>
```

Using from my react component:

```
    <Slider
      min={...}
      max={...}
      value={...}
      onChange={...}
    />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [rc-slider docs](https://github.com/react-component/slider/#common-api), you're able to pass a `handle` prop:

```
<Slider
  min={...}
  max={...}
  value={...}
  onChange={...}
  handle={() => <div className="rc-slider-handle" />}
/>
```